# Meaning of 道生一,一生二,二生三,三生万物

Tags: meaning, classical-chinese, literary-chinese

During one class we talk about how Chinese families give name to their children, however the conclusion is a little bit confusing for me.

Context: they give to a child the following name -> 冯一

[image: conclusion]

Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning I would present is

> With the principles of nature, the fundamentals were produced. Everything else are then produced from the fundamentals.

The explanation of the ***principle*** and the ***fundamentals*** differs from people to people, it depends on your belief, the major you study and other backgrounds.

I, as a physics student, would regard the ***principle*** as the physics rules and the ***fundamentals*** as particles that make up the universe.

Comment: Thank you for that answer and for the example, I will read more on Laozi thoughts.

Comment: @ClémentJean You are absolutely welcome!